# Each dev-mode edit adds another Controller instance of same class?

Tags: grails

When I 'grails run-app' each edit of a controller seems to give me a new controller instance of that class, but the previous instance(s) remain: they are listed on the default index.gsp, they show up as duplicate tabs in the Navigation plugin menu. How do I tell grails to drop the previous instances?

(Using grails 1.1.1, java 6, on Linux Fedora 11 x86_64; same thing happens if I use 'mvn grails:run-app')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.2M1 - see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4741